# Elasticpress: Multiple site search is not working in wprdpress network mode

Tags: elasticpress

Can anyone help here.

I have made a query with ep_search=>true and sites=>array(1,2),

But it takes data from site 1 not from site 2.
If we change the switch to blog 2 then it will show the data from site 2 but not from site 1.

I have follow the example from, but cannot work : https://elasticpress.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052027951-How-can-I-search-across-multiple-sites-in-a-multi-site

I have follow the example from, but cannot work : https://elasticpress.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360052027951-How-can-I-search-across-multiple-sites-in-a-multi-site